# Stereo image matching implementation in Halide

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, c++11, image

The authors of [this paper](http://www.cvlibs.net/publications/Geiger2010ACCV.pdf) compute support_points of a 900×700 image in 118 ms. I have implemented their algorithm below in Halide. In my algorithm, the nested for loops over length and width iterate over `xi` and `yi`, which are points in `output_x` and `output_y`. Over each iteration of the nested for loops, a vector top_k is computed and pushed_back into support_points. Computing this pipeline even for `left_buffer.width() == 20` and `left_buffer.height() == 20` takes 500 ms. Thus this implementation is several orders of magnitude slower.

```
// To compile and run:
// export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../bin
// g++ support.cpp -g -I ../include -I ../tools -L ../bin -lHalide `libpng-config --cflags --ldflags` -ljpeg -lpthread -ldl -o support -std=c++11 && ./support



#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include "Halide.h"
#include "halide_image_io.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "clock.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace Halide::Tools;
using namespace Halide::ConciseCasts;
using namespace Halide;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double t1 = current_time();

    Var x("x"), y("y");

    Buffer<uint8_t> left_buffer = load_image("images/stereo/bike_smallest.jpg");

    Expr clamped_x = clamp(x, 0, left_buffer.width() - 1);
    Expr clamped_y = clamp(y, 0, left_buffer.height() - 1);

    Func left_original("left_original");
    left_original(x, y) = f32(left_buffer(clamped_x, clamped_y));
    left_original.compute_root();

    // 3x3 sobel filter
    Buffer<float_t> sobel_1(3);
    sobel_1(0) = -1;
    sobel_1(1) = 0;
    sobel_1(2) = 1;

    Buffer<float_t> sobel_2(3);
    sobel_2(0) = 1;
    sobel_2(1) = 2;
    sobel_2(2) = 1;

    Func output_x_inter("output_x_inter");
    output_x_inter(x, y) = f32(left_original(x + 1, y) * sobel_1(0) + left_original(x, y) * sobel_1(1) + left_original(x - 1, y) * sobel_1(2));
    output_x_inter.compute_root();

    Func sobel_x("sobel_x");
    sobel_x(x, y) = f32(output_x_inter(x, y + 1) * sobel_2(0) + output_x_inter(x,  y) * sobel_2(1) + output_x_inter(x, y - 1) * sobel_2(2));
//    sobel_x.compute_root(); didn't work
    sobel_x.trace_stores();
    Buffer<float> output_x = sobel_x.realize(left_buffer.width(), left_buffer.height());
    output_x.set_name("output_x");

    Func sobel_y_inter("sobel_y_inter");
    sobel_y_inter(x, y) = f32(left_original(x + 1, y) * sobel_2(0) + left_original(x, y) * sobel_2(1) + left_original(x - 1, y) * sobel_2(2));

    Func sobel_y("sobel_y");
    sobel_y(x, y) = f32(sobel_y_inter(x, y + 1) * sobel_1(0) + sobel_y_inter(x, y) * sobel_1(1) + sobel_y_inter(x, y - 1) * sobel_1(2));
    sobel_y.compute_root();
    sobel_y.trace_stores();
    Buffer<float> output_y = sobel_y.realize(left_buffer.width(), left_buffer.height());
    output_y.set_name("output_y");


    int k = 4; // # of support points
    vector<pair<Expr, Expr>> support_points(k * left_buffer.width() * left_buffer.height());
    // Calculate support pixel for each
    Func support("support");
    support(x, y) = Tuple(i32(0), i32(0), f32(0));



    for (int yi = 0; yi < left_buffer.height(); yi++) {
        for (int xi = 0; xi < left_buffer.width() - 2; xi++) {
            bool left = xi < left_buffer.width() / 4;
            bool center = (xi >= left_buffer.width() / 4 && xi < left_buffer.width() * 3 / 4);
            bool right = xi >= left_buffer.width() * 3 / 4;

            vector <pair<Expr, Expr>> scan_range;
            pair <Expr, Expr> scan_height(0, (Expr) left_buffer.height());
            pair <Expr, Expr> scan_width;
            int which_pred = 0;
            if (left) {

                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) 0, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 0;
            }
            else if (center) {
                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) xi - left_buffer.width() / 4, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 1;
            }
            else if (right) {
                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 2;
            }
            else {
                cout<<"Error"<<endl;
            }

            scan_range = {scan_width, scan_height};
//            cout<<"xi "<<xi<<endl;
//            cout<<"yi "<<yi<<endl;
//            cout<<"scan_width= "<<scan_width.first<<" "<<scan_width.second<<endl;
//            cout<<"scan_height= "<<scan_height.first<<" "<<scan_height.second<<endl;


            RDom scanner(scan_range);
            Expr predicate[3] = {scanner.x != xi && scanner.y != yi, scanner.x != 0 && scanner.y != 0, scanner.x != xi && scanner.y != yi};
            scanner.where(predicate[which_pred]);
            std::vector<Expr> top_k(k * 3);
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) { // say we want top 4 support points.
                top_k[3*i] = 10000.0f;
                top_k[3*i+1] = 0;
                top_k[3*i+2] = 0;
            }

            Func argmin("argmin");
            argmin() = Tuple(top_k);
            Expr next_val = abs(output_x(xi, yi) - output_x(scanner.x, scanner.y)) + abs(output_y(xi, yi) - output_y(scanner.x, scanner.y));
            Expr next_x = scanner.x;
            Expr next_y = scanner.y;

            top_k = Tuple(argmin()).as_vector();
            // Insert a single element into a sorted list without actually branching
            top_k.push_back(next_val);
            top_k.push_back(next_x);
            top_k.push_back(next_y);
            for (int i = k; i > 0; i--) {
                Expr prev_val = top_k[(i-1)*3];
                Expr prev_x = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1];
                Expr prev_y = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2];
                Expr should_swap = top_k[i*3] < prev_val;

                top_k[(i-1)*3] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3], prev_val);
                top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 1], prev_x);
                top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 2], prev_y);
                top_k[i*3] = select(should_swap, prev_val, top_k[i*3]);
                top_k[i*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, prev_x, top_k[i*3 + 1]);
                top_k[i*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, prev_y, top_k[i*3 + 2]);
            }
            // Discard the k+1th element
            top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back();

            bool cond = xi == 10 && yi == 10;
            cout << xi << " "<< yi << " " << cond << endl;

            Expr e = argmin()[0];

            e = print_when(cond, e, "<- argmin() val");
            argmin() = Tuple(top_k);
            argmin.compute_root();
//            argmin.trace_stores();


            argmin.compile_to_lowered_stmt("argmin.html", {}, HTML);
            Realization real = argmin.realize();
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                pair<Expr, Expr> c(top_k[3*i+1], top_k[3*i+2]);
                support_points.push_back(c);
            }
        }
    }
    double t2 = current_time();

    cout<<(t2-t1)/100<<" ms"<<endl;
    cout<<"executed"<<endl;
}
```

How can I make it more efficient?

----- EDIT -----

As an answer suggested, I pulled out all the declarations out of the iterations, but this has had only a marginal effect, if any, on the performance. This is what my code looks like now:

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include "Halide.h"
#include "halide_image_io.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "clock.h"
#include <vector>

#define R 0
#define G 1
#define B 2
using namespace std;
using namespace Halide::Tools;
using namespace Halide::ConciseCasts;
using namespace Halide;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double t1 = current_time();

    Var x("x"), y("y");

    Buffer<uint8_t> left_buffer = load_image("images/stereo/bike_smallest.jpg");

    Expr clamped_x = clamp(x, 0, left_buffer.width() - 1);
    Expr clamped_y = clamp(y, 0, left_buffer.height() - 1);

    Func left_original("left_original");
    left_original(x, y) = f32(left_buffer(clamped_x, clamped_y));
    left_original.compute_root();

    // 3x3 sobel filter
    Buffer<float_t> sobel_1(3);
    sobel_1(0) = -1;
    sobel_1(1) = 0;
    sobel_1(2) = 1;

    Buffer<float_t> sobel_2(3);
    sobel_2(0) = 1;
    sobel_2(1) = 2;
    sobel_2(2) = 1;

    Func output_x_inter("output_x_inter");
    output_x_inter(x, y) = f32(left_original(x + 1, y) * sobel_1(0) + left_original(x, y) * sobel_1(1) + left_original(x - 1, y) * sobel_1(2));
    output_x_inter.compute_root();

    Func sobel_x("sobel_x");
    sobel_x(x, y) = f32(output_x_inter(x, y + 1) * sobel_2(0) + output_x_inter(x,  y) * sobel_2(1) + output_x_inter(x, y - 1) * sobel_2(2));
//    sobel_x.compute_root(); didn't work
//    sobel_x.trace_stores();
    Buffer<float> output_x = sobel_x.realize(left_buffer.width(), left_buffer.height());
    output_x.set_name("output_x");

    Func sobel_y_inter("sobel_y_inter");
    sobel_y_inter(x, y) = f32(left_original(x + 1, y) * sobel_2(0) + left_original(x, y) * sobel_2(1) + left_original(x - 1, y) * sobel_2(2));

    Func sobel_y("sobel_y");
    sobel_y(x, y) = f32(sobel_y_inter(x, y + 1) * sobel_1(0) + sobel_y_inter(x, y) * sobel_1(1) + sobel_y_inter(x, y - 1) * sobel_1(2));
    sobel_y.compute_root();
//    sobel_y.trace_stores();
    Buffer<float> output_y = sobel_y.realize(left_buffer.width(), left_buffer.height());
    output_y.set_name("output_y");


    int k = 4; // # of support points
    vector<pair<Expr, Expr>> support_points(k * left_buffer.width() * left_buffer.height());
    // Calculate support pixel for each
    Func support("support");
    support(x, y) = Tuple(i32(0), i32(0), f32(0));


    vector <pair<Expr, Expr>> scan_range(2);
    pair <Expr, Expr> scan_height(0, (Expr) left_buffer.height());
    pair <Expr, Expr> scan_width;

    std::vector<Expr> top_k(k * 3);
    Expr predicate[3];
    int count = 0;
    RDom scanner;
    bool left;
    bool center;
    bool right;
    int which_pred = 0;
    Expr next_val, next_x, next_y, prev_val, prev_x, prev_y;
    Expr should_swap;
    pair<Expr, Expr> c;


    for (int yi = 0; yi < left_buffer.height(); yi++) {
        for (int xi = 0; xi < left_buffer.width() - 2; xi++) {

            left = xi < left_buffer.width() / 4;
            center = (xi >= left_buffer.width() / 4 && xi < left_buffer.width() * 3 / 4);
            right = xi >= left_buffer.width() * 3 / 4;

            if (left) {

                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) 0, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 0;
            }
            else if (center) {
                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) xi - left_buffer.width() / 4, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 1;
            }
            else if (right) {
                    scan_width = make_pair((Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2, (Expr) left_buffer.width() / 2);
                    which_pred = 2;
            }
            else {
                cout<<"Error"<<endl;
            }

            scan_range[0] = scan_width;
            scan_range[1] = scan_height;

            // so far 1e-05 per iteration

            scanner = (scan_range); //slow 0.006

            // these three kind of slow 0.002

            predicate[0] = scanner.x != xi && scanner.y != yi;
            predicate[1] = scanner.x != 0 && scanner.y != 0;
            predicate[2] = scanner.x != xi && scanner.y != yi;
            scanner.where(predicate[which_pred]);


            // this loop is 1e-05
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) { // say we want top 4 support points.
                top_k[3*i] = 10000.0f;
                top_k[3*i+1] = 0;
                top_k[3*i+2] = 0;
            }

            Func argmin("argmin");

            // 0.003
            argmin() = Tuple(top_k);


            next_val = abs(output_x(xi, yi) - output_x(scanner.x, scanner.y)) + abs(output_y(xi, yi) - output_y(scanner.x, scanner.y));

            next_x = scanner.x;
            next_y = scanner.y;

            top_k = Tuple(argmin()).as_vector();

            // Insert a single element into a sorted list without actually branching
            top_k.push_back(next_val);
            top_k.push_back(next_x);
            top_k.push_back(next_y);

            for (int i = k; i > 0; i--) {
                prev_val = top_k[(i-1)*3];
                prev_x = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1];
                prev_y = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2];
                should_swap = top_k[i*3] < prev_val;

                top_k[(i-1)*3] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3], prev_val);
                top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 1], prev_x);
                top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 2], prev_y);
                top_k[i*3] = select(should_swap, prev_val, top_k[i*3]);
                top_k[i*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, prev_x, top_k[i*3 + 1]);
                top_k[i*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, prev_y, top_k[i*3 + 2]);
//                cout<<"(165)"<<endl;
            }

            // Discard the k+1th element
            top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back();

            argmin() = Tuple(top_k);
            argmin.compute_root();
//            argmin.trace_stores();

            argmin.compile_to_lowered_stmt("argmin.html", {}, HTML);
//            cout<<"(184)"<<endl;
            Realization real = argmin.realize(); //1.5 ms
//            cout<<"(186)"<<endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                c.first = top_k[3*i+1];
                c.second = top_k[3*i+2];
                support_points.push_back(c);
            }

            count++;
        }
    }
    double t2 = current_time();
    cout<<count<<" "<<(t2-t1)/100<<" ms"<<endl;
    cout<<"executed"<<endl;
}

```
````

Answer (score 1):

This part looks ripe for refactoring:

```
        top_k = Tuple(argmin()).as_vector();
        // Insert a single element into a sorted list without actually branching
        top_k.push_back(next_val);
        top_k.push_back(next_x);
        top_k.push_back(next_y);
        for (int i = k; i > 0; i--) {
            Expr prev_val = top_k[(i-1)*3];
            Expr prev_x = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1];
            Expr prev_y = top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2];
            Expr should_swap = top_k[i*3] < prev_val;

            top_k[(i-1)*3] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3], prev_val);
            top_k[(i-1)*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 1], prev_x);
            top_k[(i-1)*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, top_k[i*3 + 2], prev_y);
            top_k[i*3] = select(should_swap, prev_val, top_k[i*3]);
            top_k[i*3 + 1] = select(should_swap, prev_x, top_k[i*3 + 1]);
            top_k[i*3 + 2] = select(should_swap, prev_y, top_k[i*3 + 2]);
        }
        // Discard the k+1th element
        top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back(); top_k.pop_back();
```

If I understand correctly, what you're doing here is bubble-sorting a triple `(next_val, next_x, next_y)` into the proper place in vector `top_k`, and then removing the now-smallest triple from the vector.

The first thing you could do is use proper data types. Instead of triples of ints (and the continual multiplications-by-`3` that entails), you should make a struct type, like

```
struct Triple {
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
    struct descending {
        bool operator()(const Triple& a, const Triple& b) const {
            return a.value > b.value;
        }
    };
};
```

And then your insertion can become

```
std::vector<Triple> top_k = [...]
Triple new_item = { next_x, next_y, next_val };
auto insertion_point = std::lower_bound(top_k.begin(), top_k.end(), new_item, Triple::descending);
top_k.insert(insertion_point, new_item);
top_k.pop_back();
```

(Or maybe my `descending` should be `ascending`. I didn't expend many brain cells on it.)

---

If your algorithm *depends* on this operation, then (A) maybe you should use a `priority_queue`, (B) maybe you should use a `priority_queue` that supports the [`replace_top` operation](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/04/27/pq-replace-top/), and (C) *certainly* you should use something that never allocates memory in your inner loop.

Right now it seems you're spending a lot of time resizing STL containers in the inner loop, which causes heap traffic. For performance, instead of

```
for (int yi = 0; yi < left_buffer.height(); yi++) {
    for (int xi = 0; xi < left_buffer.width() - 2; xi++) {
        [...]
        vector<pair<Expr, Expr>> scan_range = {scan_width, scan_height};
```

you should do

```
vector<pair<Expr, Expr>> scan_range(2);
for (int yi = 0; yi < left_buffer.height(); yi++) {
    for (int xi = 0; xi < left_buffer.width() - 2; xi++) {
        [...]
        scan_range[0] = scan_width;
        scan_range[1] = scan_height;
```

This puts the heap allocation *outside* the inner loop, which means now you're doing 1 allocation where in your original code you're doing `left_buffer.height()*(left_buffer.width() - 2)` allocations.

Applying this strategy to your other allocations (e.g. `top_k` itself) should give a *huge* performance boost.

---

EDIT: Looking for more wasted cycles in your updated code, I see the following four lines at the end of your loop:

```
        argmin.compile_to_lowered_stmt("argmin.html", {}, HTML);
//            cout<<"(184)"<<endl;
        Realization real = argmin.realize(); //1.5 ms
//            cout<<"(186)"<<endl;
```

Variable `real` is never used, so you can eliminate it. If I'm interpreting that comment correctly, eliminating `real` will save you 1.5ms per loop.

`argmin.compile_to_lowered_stmt(...)` seems to be Halide's equivalent of a "debugging printf." It will do a lot of work to compile the function, and then also open a file, write to it, and close the file again. Those are both horribly slow operations. So unless you *need* `argmin.html` — and I don't see how you possibly could, since you overwrite it for every pixel of the input — you should eliminate this line.

In general, when you're trying to make something run fast, you should go over each line with a critical eye and ask, "How expensive is this line? What benefit does this line get me?" If it's expensive and has no benefit, then remove or rewrite it.

Comment: Please check out my edit.